# how i can SUM field values from two or more tables in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have six tables with each has two columns named (meal, cost).
I can SUM meal of one table.
but I want to SUM the total meal of every table.

but like this.i have six tables. and I want to SUM the cost of every table at a time.

```
$qq="select SUM(cost5) as 'sumcost' from shawon"; 
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$qq); $data=mysqli_fetch_array($res);  
echo "<div class='container'>". "sum of cost: ".$data['sumcost']."</div>";
```

is there any way  to do it?

Comment: $qq="select SUM(cost5) as 'sumcost' from shawon";
$res=mysqli_query($conn,$qq);
$data=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo "<div class='container'>". "sum of cost: ".$data['sumcost']."</div>";

i use this code

Comment: Why do you have them as separate tables? If they have the exact same data, can't they be in 1 table? If they must be separate tables, you can sum them separately, union the results together in a subquery and sum that.

Comment: Check the answer given below +1, but the need to union _six_ separate tables might be a symptom of poor table design, and that you shouldn't have this data spread across six separate tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use union all for buil an unique table with the same column  mean, cost form each of six tables

```
select meal, sum(cost)
from (
  select  meal,cost
  from table1 
  union all 
  select  meal,cost
  from table2
  union all 
  select  meal,cost
  from table3
  union all 
  select  meal,cost
  from table4
  union all 
  select  meal,cost
  from table5
  union all 
  select  meal,cost
  from table6
  ) t 
  group by  meal
```